# Дополнительная секция на сайт

Tags: wordpress, веб-сайт

ССылка на сайт - http://gelios-pnz.ru
Добрый день, проблема такая:
Нужно добавить дополнительную секцию, например как "наши преимущества", хочу доп секцию с "отзывами"
Но дело в том, что я чайник))
Секцию через FTP я создала, а как ее дальше сделать, чтобы она отображалась?
Очень надеюсь на вашу помощь

Comment: Внешний вид -> меню -> выбираете необходимое меню -> выбрать нужную для добавления страницу или то чем у вас является секция -> затем нажать "добавить в меню"

Comment: мне не нужно меню, мне нужна секция внизу дополнительная

Comment: если весь ваш сайт состоит из одной страница с секциями, то можете зайти в редактор этой страницы и добавить секцию в конец. Открываете страницу в админке -> Elementor -> добавить цекцию

Comment: главная страница создана не в элементор, им даже редактировать нельзя.

Comment: У вас на странице покупки шаблона написано "Поддержка Drag & Drop сортировки блоков на главной". Может там же можно и создать свой блок? Вы смотрели в админке пункт меню "Внешний вид" - "Настройка"? И в пункте меню "Страницы", вообще есть главная страница? Если да, то можно ли ее редактировать?

Comment: "Поддержка Drag & Drop сортировки блоков на главной"-аааа, я не пойму где это))))
главную страницу редактировать через элементор нельзя, только через код!!